# pass "git describe" output to Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bash, ant

Is there a way to pass the output of `git describe --tag` to my Java application at compile time?  I'd like to use that in my about box to display version info.  I'm using Eclipse to build, but I can use ant if necessary.

With C code, I can pass `-D'REV="$(shell git describe --tag)"'` to my gcc compiler, and my code can pick that up.  I'm hoping there's something similar in Java.

Comment: @Dustin: It looks like a valid compiler option for `gcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ant` is acceptable, it supports a similar [command line option](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline).

As a concrete example, this line in an `ant` script

```
<echo>property: ${property}</echo>
```

when invoked with the following command,

```
$ ant -Dproperty="$(git --version)"
```

produces the following output on the console,

```
[echo] property: git version 1.7.5.4
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution.  That would allow me to use System.getProperty to read the -D value?

Comment: Not directly; using the  example above, you could add the value named `property` to your [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) as a runtime parameter.